# upload file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

hi i am trying to upload a file in codeigniter but some how the file is not being uploaded. Here is the code,

```
$config = array(

                   'file_name'     => 'user',
                   'max_size'      => 100,
                   'upload_path'   => realpath(APPPATH.'../files/'),
                                );




                $this->load->library('upload',$config);

                $this->upload->do_upload();


                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
```

this is actually the code of a method in a model which i am calling through a controller method which in turn is a method i cll on form submit.

the file reaches the method it shows uploading in the browser but when i see file name key of $upload_data it has user without extension and according to me there should be extension too right? . also when i try to print extension it shows nothing. BTW i am trying to upload  small 3gp file approx 770kbs taken on my mobile. There is nothing in files folder too. Thank you for your help

Stilll nothing, please help.

Checked for permissions

Comment: For starters, you are missing an apostrophe after `'../files/`.

Comment: sorry that was a copy mistake..

Comment: Please post the HTML form which you use to upload.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) page for upload data.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's one of two issues:

1) You aren't including the list of valid extensions, as [shown in the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) (under *The Controller*)

For this, you need to add `'allowed_types' => '3gp'` to your configuration.

2) Permissions issues on the upload path

You'll need to ensure that the `files` folder is writable, along with *every folder above it* for Apache.

See [this StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262327/apachephp-write-permissions-on-unix) for more on #2.

Comment: 2nd permissions is the first thing i checked

Comment: Try using this for the allowed_types: `audio/3gpp|video/3gpp|3gp` - I forgot it needs the mimetype.